# Is the precise definition of a limit worth covering in Calc 1?

Tags: limits, education, epsilon-delta

I'm teaching calc 1 this semester and am trying to decide if I should cover the precise definition of a limit.

My first impression was that I should. It helped me to gain a deeper understanding of calculus.

But I think most students won't gain that understanding and the ones who do are mostly math majors who will have plenty of other opportunities to learn it down the road. So I could use the time to focus more on other concepts.

Any input on this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: I've tutored Calc I for quite a while now. I'm of the opinion that unless you decide to be a math major, it's pointless to cover the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition. Sure, it does give the students the introduction to "rigorous" mathematics, but not everyone is going to find that useful, and in fact, it may confuse a lot of students, esp. non-math majors. Personally, I learned $\delta$-$\epsilon$ better when I took Real Analysis than when I was tutoring Calc. I prior to that.

Comment: By the way, you may find [Math Educators SE](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) helpful as well, but cross-posting is frowned upon.

Comment: @Clarinetist Thanks. I didn't know about that SE site. My question seems already to [basically have been asked](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/484/epsilons-and-deltas-in-a-first-calculus-course/493#493).

Comment: Having never taught a math class, I can only relate my own experience.  I didn't understand the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition when I was taught it in Calc I.  In fact, my Calc III professor didn't even cover it rigorously, he just gave us the main idea in terms of neighborhoods (which he did define, but we weren't really required to know it).  It wasn't until real analysis that I learned the rigorous definition.  By that point I'd had enough experience with limits that it immediately clicked.  That seems to have worked out well enough in my case.

Comment: It depends on the level of the students. For almost all classes, it is a very bad idea.  A good basic understanding of limits can be reached without $\epsilon$-$\delta$.

Comment: I agree with @André. Most Calc I courses are basically cookbook calculus, and covering the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition is counterproductive. There may be a few places where this isn’t the case, but in general I’d say that the only exceptions are honors calculus sections, and not all of them: one has to distinguish sections that are part of a general honors program from those that are specifically *mathematics* honors sections.

Comment: One trouble that grad students often have when teaching a beginning calculus course is that with full good intention they want to tell their students "the whole truth."  It is possible to give a reasonably high level course without introducing $\epsilon$-$\delta$ and its relatives. "Analysis" can wait.

Comment: Thanks @AndréNicolas, I think I'll take your advice. And in case you think it would be good, say for the integrity of this site, to have an accepted answer, note that I'd accept yours.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks. What I just said to Andre goes for you as well.

Comment: I feel awkward about giving an answer, because what I wrote is a matter of opinion, albeit strongly held opinion.  It is backed by the experience of being too many times "in charge" of a first year calculus course with many sections. I have also taught the smallish honours course, that had very good students. Even there, $\epsilon$-$\delta$ is I think not high priority: there are many other ways to enrich.